# Jenkins job not stopping after running a remote script

Tags: shell, jenkins, executable-jar

I am building an executable jar file using jenkins and copying into a remote server. After the copying, I need to run the jar file in the remote server. I am using `SSH Plugin` for executing the remote script.

The remote script looks like this:

**startServer.sh**

```
pkill -f MyExecutable
nohup java -jar /home/administrator/app/MyExecutable.jar &
```

Jenkins is able to execute the script file, but it is not stopping the job after the execution. It is still continuing the process and showing the log in jenkins console. This is creating problems since these continuing jobs blocks other jobs to execute.

How can I stop the job once the script is executed.

Comment: I am actually running an executable jar after copying to remote server. I am not executing the jar file from jenkins, but just invoking a shell script which is in the remote server.

Comment: @l0b0, wish I could give you -1. When you deploy a package/application, you start it. That's called automation and that's what Jenkins is for, among other things. If all your Jenkins does is build, and not deploy + start, then it's not CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the problem. I am posting it for others sake.

I used ssh **-f** user@server ....

this solved my problem.

```
ssh -f  root@${server} sh /home/administrator/bin/startServer.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue using the **Publish Over SSH Plugin**. For some reason Jenkins wasn't stopping after executing the remote script. Ticking the below configuration fixed the problem.

SSH Publishers > Transfers > Advanced > Exec in pty

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for you my friend.

Make sure to add **usePty: true** in the pipeline that you are using which will enable the execution of sudo commands that require a tty (and possibly help in other scenarios too.)

```
sshTransfer(
     sourceFiles: "target/*.zip", 
     removePrefix: "target", 
     remoteDirectory: "'/root/'yyyy-MM-dd",
     execTimeout: 300000, 
     usePty: true, 
     verbose: true,
     execCommand: '''
        pkill -f MyExecutable
        nohup java -jar /home/administrator/app/MyExecutable.jar &
        echo $! >> /tmp/jenkins/jenkins.pid
        sleep 1
     '''
)
```